# Disable internet connection permanently windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, internet

I have used  "Ipconfig/release" command to disable internet but it 
allows to connect to internet after I restart my PC.

Is there anyway to disable internet permanently, and a method to restore it when we need it.

I just want to know how to block certain PC from my router(Mac address blocking or similar thing).

Please help.
Thank you...

Comment: Do u want to disable internet permanently or only an especific link?

Comment: I want to disable internet connection permanantly

Comment: You contradict yourself when saying "*disable internet permanently, and a method to restore it when we need it*". Permanent means it will never work again. Please clarify. Are you asking how to disable the connection until you want to use it?

Comment: @mmc, when you say "I am expecting more than that", you mean something that will be difficult to restore not knowing the steps or without technical knowledge?

Comment: I resolved it by blocking the MAC address of my wifi adapter. So I could restore the internet connection by logging to router settings by another device and I could remove that device from MAC address from blacklist. and restore internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came up with a solution.
Since I want to stop permanently connecting to from specific PC.
Select the Physical address/MAC address of the router and write it down.

Then I log on to my router configuration page (in my case I am using Huawei 4G Router)
If you did not manually setup the login user account setting default user name and password is printed under the router.

Then go to security Tab. Make sure your Firewall level is Medium. if it is not Please make it Medium and submit.

After that got to MAC Filtering.(which is also under security tab)
select the radio button Blacklist.

Then click on the button add Item  There you can Insert the MAC address of the wifi adapter which you use to connect and block the internet.

Then click submit.

If you do not know how to find the MAC address of wifi adapter please follow
these steps.

Opened command prompt and and typed `ipconfig/all`
since it gives all information about physical Address(MAC Address) of your WIFI adapter.

Please note after you blacklist your MAC address from the router you won't be able even login to router page. so keep another device to login to that router to remove that router from the blacklist.

Also if you do not have any other device you can solve it by resetting your router, from physical component of your router.

Thanks everyone who support me by sharing their knowledge with me..

Comment: Easier to disable your network adapter(s) in Device Manger

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few ways..

- Give the network card a manual IP address that is completely off the network.
- Disable the IPV4 option of the network card.
- If wifi, then just do not enter the network key when prompted AFTER you remove the saved config info form Network and Sharing Center.. Manage Wireless Networks and removing your wifi from there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Do any of these provide any kind of advantage over just disabling the adapter from the network control panel?

Comment: The advantage would be quick method to connect compare to enabling the adapter and then connecting (if needed)
Another adv. I can think of is if you plan on using VLANs then you can switch easily by changing IP addresses manually.

Answer (score 2):

Does your computer have a physical NIC? If so, simply remove the network interface card.

If it's integrated into the motherboard, go into your Device Manager, go to Network Adapter, right click, and select "Disable." This will disable the network interface and will not allow any incoming/outgoing network traffic. This solution isn't PERMANENT, however. To re-enable network communications, you would have to go back into your device manager.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable all the internet connections ;

Please RUN the command ncpa.cpl via RUN-Command Dialog [Windows+R]

and use Right-Click on every Network Adapter to disable the network connections

Answer (score -1):

Pretty funny question.

But one way to go is to uninstall all network adapters drivers from device manager. 
(local area network, wifi etc)

But be sure to have the drivers already downloaded and saved somewhere just incase you need to revert.

Secondly, you could run services.msc as an administrator.

Go stop all network related services, (network list, network connections, network interface store, dhcp, dns, etc) and set startup type on all of those services to manual.

Pretty sure your Internet would get lost forever!

Comment: No need to uninstall drivers, just select "disable" in device manager.

Comment: @moab We all know you can disable your network adapter driver. But that option had already been given (before my post) and OP didn't accept them as answers...making me feel he wanted a more permanent option...thus I advised uninstallation of the adapter driver...noting that he should have them downloaded incase he decides to revert. My answer is a valid option to prevent Internet connectivity on any PC, I still don't understand your problem with my post.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was just set the network gateway to be something that won't get you online (perhaps the loopback address) or just a bogus network address. I did this for my parents' Windows XP partition of their computer, so that it would be able to access the local network but not the Internet. The gateway address tells the computer where to forward requests to external IP addresses. If it is set to an IP address that doesn't exist or that doesn't have Internet access, those requests won't go anywhere.

Comment: FYI: you can leave gateway empty, then Windows won't even try to go there.

Comment: I didn't even realize this. I had assumed it would complain unless it contained a valid IP address.